# why safari doesn't authenticate me during auto fill?

Tags: macos, safari, password, login

I have saved my username and password(let's say of a website abc.com) in Passwords on macOS. Now, when I go to that website on Safari, and I click inside login username, it prompts me to autofill. With one single click on that prompt, it does the autofill of my username and password. Then I just click the login button and I am logged in!

Nice and good!

But, just wondering, why it didn't ask me to authenticate etc. just clicked on the suggested prompt and simply filled in! Yes, its very smooth experience, but feels little dangerous. For example, let's say I just moved away to get a cup of coffee and then this naughty kid tried to do some experiment, then the kid can simply log into including all of websites (important and real ones too). Kid will also have simple and easy access for all the logins.

Am I missing something here?

Passwords (in System Preferences) or Passwords tab in Safari preferences force require to authenticate every time we try to access it even though the same Mac user is currently accessing it. This is good (as it provides 2nd layer of security considering these are sensitive info, not like just any other file etc.)! Can't it be same with Safari AutoFill too?

Answer (score 0):

In System Settings, go to Settings > Touch ID & Password and enable "Use Touch ID for autofilling passwords."

Enabling this option will prompt for your fingerprint or password when autofilling. If the display is closed it will immediately ask for your password.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to request your password if you haven't enrolled a fingerprint.

Answer (score -1):

You missed locking your computer before walking away ;)

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd>  will lock your screen, requiring your password or TouchID to access again.

Comment: I know I can lock computer, but didn't want to because I want to let the kid momentarily use for other kid games in other tabs in Safari.

Comment: No computer is secure if you let someone else use your account.